# automate webpage button click in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir-webdriver

I am simply looking to automate a button click on a homepage. I am using the following snippet of code

```
Given /^I press "(.*)"$/ do |action|
  browser.button(:text => action).click
end
```

My feature file has the following

```
Scenario: Default Search 
    Given I press "Search"
```

On executing the feature file, I receive the following error

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
Ambiguous match of "I press "Search"":

C:/Users/............test/features/step_definitions/Moorings.rb:8:in `/^I press "(.*)"$/'
```

Comment: Looks like you have more than one button with the text `Search` on the page. Do you?

Comment: Yep it looks like there is more then 1 search. I am using the following page www.moorings.com

Comment: ohh.. then it is really simple. try using something that will be unique, an ID for example. I'll drop an example as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Haa... you have like 3 occurrence of the text `"Search"` on that page (www.moorings.com), so the `watir` driver does not really know which one to click.

As I mentioned above, try to use something unique, maybe an `id`, as below:

```
#step definition
Given /^I press "(.*)", with id "(.*)"$/ do |text, id|
  browser.button(id: id, :text => text).when_present.fire_event :click
end

#feature
Scenario: Default Search 
    Given I press "Search", with id "edit-search"
```

Notice that I have added another constraint of id to the attributes to search for.

Also notice that I added an extra layer of check: `.when_present`. This will ensure that the test waits for the specified button to appear on the page before attempting to click it. A timeout of about 30 seconds is attached to this however.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this.I am however getting the following error message with this new code.

Given I press "Search", with id "edit-search"
      undefined local variable or method `browser' for #<Object:0x298a1f0> (NameError)

Comment: I in fact made an error with the naming of the variable.